# Error while installing RVM on ubuntu 11.04. Seems to be git clone's error

Tags: git, rvm, git-clone

When I try to install RVM the following error shows up:

```
$ bash < <(curl -s https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm)
Cloning into rvm...
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Cloning into rvm...
error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 100
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

ERROR: Unable to clone the RVM repository, attempted both git:// and https://
```

This is a `git clone` error I'm getting recently. e.g When I try to clone nodejs.

```
error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 100
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Works for me...
Transient issue on the server or network issue on your side ?

Comment: This user is not responding anymore, Guess hes got the answer :)

Comment: This seems to be an issue with my ISP! thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem you're having some sort of network issue that is preventing you
from retrieving the Git repository.  The [RVM script](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm) attempts to
clone the repository first using
`git clone --depth 1 git://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm.git`, and if that fails,
using `git clone https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm.git`.  Git uses
[libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/).  The `result=56` part of the `RPC failed` error is the
[libcurl error code](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html); `56` means `Failure with receiving network data.`.
The `HTTP code = 100` part is the [HTTP server status code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) that
was returned to you; `100` means `The client SHOULD continue with its request.`.

Your best bet is probably to start a network traffic sniffer
(on Ubuntu, you can use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)) to see exactly what packets are
being transmitted/received on your workstation.  Try installing RVM on different workstations in your network and on different networks.  I did not have any issues on my machine.