# Git push to GitHub remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: git, github

This is my first post on SO, so sorry if I'm doing this wrong!

Anyway, I have a problem with my website's git repo.  I've been trying to push from my local gi repo to my repo on GitHub, and everytime I do, I get the following:

```
Counting objects: 36, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (26/26), done.
Writing objects: 100% (26/26), 752.97 KiB, done.
Total 26 (delta 10), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 100
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I've tried using both the https and ssh URLs.  I use git from the mac CLI.  I've already successfully pushed a test commit containing a blank file to the repo from another directory.  I even copied all changes I made to this other directory and tried the push from another place to no avail.  It seems that no matter what I do, this push keeps failing.

I found a solution listed elsewhere on the web that suggested increasing the http.postBuffer in the git config file, however this also doesn't seem to solve the situation.  I'm at a complete loss and this has halted all of my forward progress.  Does anybody have some insight?

Comment: I wonder where are you? Have you tried to use VPN?

Comment: I'm having issues with pushing to repositories too except mine just slows to a crawl when I push.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the issue persists still today.

The [GitHub status history](https://www.githubstatus.com/) reported a few hours ago:

> We are investigating issues with slow repository clones and pushes.

If this is persistent, then, as it is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7639888/6309), it is a network issue from your libcurl ("Failure with receiving network data").

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  This problem actually resolved itself last night and I'm sure that it had to do with GitHub's status.